# Convert mysql irregular time series data to regular sequence

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of temperature data, updated every 5-15 mins by multiple sensors.
The data is essentially this: unique id, device(sensor id), timestamp, value(float)
The sensors does not have an accurate clock, so the readings are doomed to skew over time, so I'm unable to use things like group by hour in mysql to get a reading of the last 24h of temperature data.
My solution as a php programmer would be to make a pre-processor that reads all the un-processed readings and "join them" in a table.
There must be others than me who has this need to "downscale" x-minute/hour reads down to one per hour, to use in lets say graphing.

My problem is how do I calculate the rounded hour value from one or several readings.

For example, I have 12 readings over 2,5 hours, and I need an explicit value for each whole hour for all these readings.

Data:

```
Date                 Device  Value
2016-06-27 12:15:15, TA,     23.5
2016-06-27 12:30:19, TA,     23.1
2016-06-27 12:45:35, TA,     22.9
2016-06-27 13:00:55, TA,     22.5
2016-06-27 13:05:15, TA,     22.8
2016-06-27 13:35:35, TA,     23.2
```

I'm not that much into statistical math, so "standard deviation" and the likes are citys in Russia for me.

Also, the devices go to sleep sometimes, and does not always transmit a temperature.

Feel free to ask me to add info to the question, as I'm not sure what you guys need to answer this.

The most important parts is this:
1. I'm using MySQL, and that's not going to change.
2. I'm hoping for a solution (or tips) in php, though tips in many other languages also would help my understanding. I'm primarily a PHP programmer though, so answers in that language would be most appreciated.

Edit: I would like to specify a few points.
Because the time data recorded from the sensors may be inaccurate, I'm relying on the SQL insert time. That way the time is controlled by one device only, the controller that's inserting the data.

For example, if I select 30 timestamp/value pairs in a 24h period, I would like to "combine" these to 24 timestamp/value pairs, using an average to combine the overflowing data.
I'm not that good to explain, but I hope this makes it clearer.

Also, would love either a clean SQL way of doing it, but also a PHP way of looping through 30 rows to produce 24 whole hour rows of data.

My goal is to have one row for every hour, with an accurate timestamp and temperature value. Mainly because most graphing libraries expect that kind of input. Especially when I have more than one series in a graph.

At some point, I may find it useful to show a graph for let's say the last six hours, with a 15 minute accuracy.

The clue is that I don't want to change the raw data, just find a way to extract/compute linear results from it.

Comment: voting to close as too broad. but exactly how do you want to handle the data if the times aren't and can't be accurate? is that `13:00:55` value to be counted in the `1pm` grouping, or might it actually be `12pm` because the clock's off by 56 seconds? perhaps if your sensor transmitted what their time was when they took the reading, you could normalizebefore going into the db. "hmm. sensor said it's 12:03pm, but it's really 12:04, so the sensor's off by 1 minute".

Comment: @Bob You could probably use the [automatic initialization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) of your timesamp column when you get data from sensors. This way you could ignore the time data from sensors as you consider it inaccurate.

Comment: The thing is that if I get a reading with timestamp 11:55:00, and a later reading with timestamp 12:05:00, I would like to calculate an average of the two as 12:00:00, to be able to use it in my graphing. Obviously, this does not work if I don't have a value on both sides of the wanted timestamp (12:00:00), but I can ignore "future" values until I get a new reading. So, it's the "formula" I'm after, how to convert "11:55:00,16.6" and "12:05:00,16.8" into "12:00:00,16.7" (using pretty numbers)

Comment: @postrel The timestamps are accurate enough, because all sensors readings is registered with the insert time on the sql server (I don't really trust the sensor dates). I may not have been accurate enough in my question since english is not my native language. The question is updated with some more details.

Comment: @Bob How do want to round the hours? E.g. `10h00s00 - 10h29s59` to `10h00` and `10h30s00 - 10h59s59` to `11h00`

Answer (score 0):

How I would try to handle this is;

Take day start value; `01/01/2016 00:00:00` and do a 'between' 'sql' in MySQL, progressing every hour. So the first 'sql' would be like;

'select avg(temp_value) from table where date between 01/01/2016 00:00:00 and 01/01/2016 00:59:99' and progress on by the hour.

The sql isn't correct, and the entire 24hr period can be written out programmatically, but I think this will start you on your way.

Comment: Then I would need one SQL for every hour for a 24h query, I was hoping to be able to use some clever grouping to get a longer range result set with one query. Or maybe some formula I could use when I loop through the results of a 24h query to generate an array of 24 items with values for each whole hour. I understand that this is very broad, and I'm ready to accept this answer unless someone has some existing code examples/library hints of something that could help. I'm probably able to do some clever programing to solve it, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel ;)

Comment: This is a help site, I doubt people will have ready solutions. if you know php, its really not that hard. If you need a ready made solution you can use a site like elance, and post a job. Or I can make one for moolah. OR you could start on the code and ask for help when you get stuck. People aren't born clever, their will to learn makes them clever :)